# Available Catalogue endpoint returns empty data array instagram graph api

Tags: node.js, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have been using the sandbox tool provided by meta only I have created a catalogue of which i want to create a post. But as I run the /available_catalogs endpoint it returns me an empty data array.
The permissions I have given:

email
catalog_management
pages_show_list
business_management
instagram_basic
instagram_content_publish
pages_read_engagement
pages_manage_metadata
pages_read_user_content
pages_manage_posts
pages_manage_engagement
instagram_shopping_tag_products
instagram_manage_events
public_profile

Note: I don't have a instagram shop I just have a catalogue